# Spring MVC and Backbone.js Integration Issue

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I am trying to understand the integration of Spring MVC with backbone.js as its view technology. I find a couple of examples online such as [here](https://github.com/sdeleuze/spring-backbone-todo/) and [here too](https://github.com/consileonpl/spring-3.1-backbone.js-todo-list) However, in both of these samples, I am facing the same issues that the Spring MVC controller (the TodoController in the first link and TaskController in the second) does not seem to get called.

First, there are no log messages printed (even if I do a desperate *System.out.println()* in the controller class). Second, when I try to set break points in the controller classes and go into debug mode, it was not stopped at all, but the example is accessible  through localhost:8080/todo  (Assume that is the url of the deployed war file). In both examples, a code based configuration approach is used (there is no web.xml). So I am wondering, does the controller class ever got called?

I have been stumbling on this for the weekend. So I would really appreciate it if someone can point me the right direction. Thanks!!!

Comment: have you tried CURLing to your server? It's probably a mapping issue, so pasting some of your own code might help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer soulcheck :)

I went  back to the old fashioned web.xml as opposed to the code-based configuration approach, and I am able to see that the controller class gets properly scanned and called, as printed by the log!! I do not know why though, but i just have new respect for web.xml :)